# Generating random valued random points using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, point, random

I want my area filled radomly with a number of  points with a number of random numerical values in the range i specify. Other than tediously creating each point and filling up random values, is there any better method?

Answer (score 4):

If you have an Advanced license or Spatial Analyst or 3D Analyst, you can use the [Create Random Points tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-random-points.htm).

You can then add a field and populate it with random values within a specified range with this Python code snippet (change the `fc`, `field_name` and range values, then copy-paste the code in the Python window in ArcMap or ArcCatalog):

```
import arcpy, random
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "field_name") as cur:
    for row in cur:
        row[0] = random.randint(0, 100)
        cur.updateRow(row)
```

This will generate integer values between 0 and 100. Python offers other [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) functions if you need another type of range.

Comment: Thanks. Generating random points was easy. But I am not being able to generate random values for those points. When I use the expression you gave, all the values of the field get populated by a single random value. There is no variation in its value. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I've modified my answer to generate different random values for each row. Using Python is necessary for this.

Comment: By the way, which version of ArcGIS do you use? The Calculate Field expression I first suggested should work, but there is a [bug](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDk5NzQ0) in 10.2.1 - which doesn't seem to be solved yet  anyway.

Comment: Its 10.3 but your code is not working. Could you see what mistake I did? I know nothing of python u know and I am new in GIS too. 

>>>  import arcpy, random
... with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("random_points","rainfall_in_mm") as cur:
... for row in cur:
... row[0]=random.randint(1000, 1400)
... cur.updateRow(row)
... 
Parsing error IndentationError: unexpected indent (line 1)
>>>

Comment: Make sure you respect the structure, indentation is important with Python: 0 tabs at line 1 and 2 - 1 tab at line 3 - 2 tabs at lines 4 & 5.

Comment: Great! You can check the answer to mark your question as solved then.